# FullCalendar - is it possible to change/add text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Is it possible to dynamically change / add text or whatever to every day as shown on the picture below?

After check with debugger every day has other css name.

[fullCalendar.io](http://fullcalendar.io/)

[image]

Comment: Are you speaking about this https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar one ? (to be sure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do believe a colleague of mine used `dayRender` a few days ago for this exact purpose.

Something like this might work, however it is untested code.

```
dayRender: function (date, cell) {
    cell.text(moment(date).format('DD'));
}
```

We are using the [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) library to format the date on the cell.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use, it's a bit complex, but you'll probably find what you want to do.
It use a JS function to change on fly the list of the event supplied to FullCallendar and a JS hook to add a html tag (Glyphicon) on specific event.

```
  // JSON of all events
var allEvents = <?php echo $json; ?>;

  // set the fullCalendar
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

  header: {
    left: '',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'prev,next today'
  },
  weekends:false,
  fixedWeekCount:false,
    // our own JS function to filter the event
  events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
    var filteredEvents = [];
    var noDuplicateAssignment = [];
      // we walk on every event to filter every duplicate
    $.each(
      allEvents,
      function (key, oneEvent) {
          // we just display allUnique
        if (noDuplicateAssignment.indexOf(oneEvent.id) < 0) {
          filteredEvents.push(oneEvent);
          noDuplicateAssignment.push(oneEvent.id);
        }
      }
    );
      // we supply our events to the fullCalendar callback
    callback(filteredEvents);
  },
    // hook to add the glyphicon on electronic==TRUE event
  eventRender: function (event, element) {
    if(event.electronic)
      element.find('.fc-content').prepend(
        '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i> '
        );
  }
});
```

---

If you are speaking about the content, the best is to use a JSON formatted input for your data.

With the Json, you can edit the JavaScript Json object and call the rendering of this new object to get what you want. http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_array/

Comment: I am already getting events from JSON to render events  but I dont know how do I get to those days number at the bottom of day cell :(

Comment: @miechooy What ? explain a bit more what you want in you question please, as it seem I absolutely don't understand in fact... is just putting the day number at the bottom of the cell ?

Comment: I want to put my own text instead

Comment: @miechooy "put my own text" is not explicit enough. you have many way to do it, the question is what you want exactly to do ? if it's changing the full list of event ? adding a part on the event before displaying ? filtered them ? I've updated my post with the code I use, may you find something useful (I more or less do all the above function...)